# python notepad++ specify arguments sys.argv[1]

Tags: python, notepad++

I am using notepad++ in Windows to execute my python scripts.
I am using NppExec or PyNpp for this purpose and this is working well.

However, I can't find nowhere how to specify an argument to the script, in order to simply call my script like this on Linux:

```
$ python myscript.py blah
```

`blah` is retrieved in my script by `sys.argv[1]`

Is it possible to do such a thing in Notepad++? Is there a plugin to do this?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What do you mean by "do such a thing in Notepad++"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really the only option you have is to go to NppExec->Execute which should open a dialog.

Then enter `python ..\path\to\script\myscript.py blah`, replacing ..\path\to\script\ with the full path to your python file. Then whenever you press <kbd>F6</kbd>, the program will run. You can follow these steps again to change the argument.

NOTE: Pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> will **not** open the dialog, it will only run the currently configured execution settings.